# how to get a html tag's attribute value, using class name in javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I have 10 "tr" tags like this:

```
<tr class="jtable-data-row jtable-row-even" data-record-key="13">
<td class="jtable-selecting-column">
<input type="checkbox">
<label for="">
<span></span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="jtable-data-row" data-record-key="11">
<td class="jtable-selecting-column">
<input type="checkbox">
<label for="">
<span></span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
```

how can I get the value of "data-record-key" if it's check box is checked? which class or ID name should I use?

And I must say that I can't change the html code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're responding to an event on the checkbox, `this` within the event handler will refer to the checkbox related to the event. So within the event handler:

```
var key = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-record-key');
```

- `this` - The checkbox element the event relates to
- `$(...)` - Wrap it in a jQuery instance
- `.closest('tr')` - Find its nearest ancestor that's a `tr`
- `.attr('data-record-key')` - Get the `data-record-key` attribute from it

Alternately, instead of `.closest('tr')` you could use `.closest('[data-record-key]')` to find the nearest ancestor that has the attribute.

---

Or if you're trying to find the key for *each* checkbox that's checked, you can query that like so:

```
var checkedRecordKeys = $("[data-record-key] input[type=checkbox]").map(function() {
    return this.checked
               ? $(this).closest("[data-record-key]").attr("data-record-key")
               : undefined;
}).get();
```

`checkedRecordKeys` will be an array of all of the `data-record-key` values for rows with checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an alternative - you can also get the data-attribute value using `data()` like this:

```
$("input").on("click", function () {
 var dVal = $(this).closest("tr").data("recordKey");
 alert(dVal);
});
```

for `<tr class="jtable-data-row jtable-row-even" data-record-key="13">`

Fiddle: [Getting data value using data()](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/qc06ypzy/)

Reference for jQuery data: [api.jquery.com/data/](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

For accessing the data value, the name of the data-attribute is loosing the "data-" and the hyphens (if any); first characters after hyphens get camelCased, therefore `data-record-key` is accessed as `recordKey`.